# Volume encrypted after failed downgrade

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, encryption, downgrade

I tried to downgrade my Mac OS from Catalina to Mojave, but the installing procedure could not manage to reach the end. Therefore, I reinstalled (using Wi-Fi installation) Catalina. 
As a result, I now have two partitions in my hard disk called "Machintosh HD - Data", one of which contains my old data. Thing is, this old volume is now encrypted and I cannot seem to decrypt it, nor can I access the folders it contains. 
In particular, trying to input 
`diskutil apfs decryptVolume disk1s1` on Terminal, I get the message 
`User 11855E8B-E1EE-3DB5-ACDB-3C9D60CF4AEC (the "Disk" user) does not exist on APFS Volume disk1s1`.

Comment: Grab your backup disk and restore last known good snapshot...

Comment: Nuke the drive and reinstall Mojave, then restore your backup.  If you have TWO -Data  volumes, then you didn't erase the drive correctly when you tried to install Mojave the first time.